# How to write Query on Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, symfony-2.8

How can I write this in my Repository to be able to work with it in my controller ?

```
SELECT COUNT(id_pnc) 
FROM programmevol p
WHERE p.id_pnc IN (
    SELECT id_pnc 
    FROM programmevol A 
    WHERE p.id_pnc=A.id_pnc
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
);
```

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#data-retrieval You can get connection from entity manager and execute raw sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
public function findWhateverYouWant()
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($em);

    $sql = sprintf('SELECT COUNT(id_pnc) 
                    FROM programmevol p
                    WHERE p.id_pnc IN ( SELECT id_pnc 
                                        FROM programmevol A 
                                        WHERE p.id_pnc=A.id_pnc
                                        HAVING COUNT(*)>1
                                       )', 
                    $rsm->generateSelectClause()
                   );

    $query = $em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Comment: i dosen't work when i did  $var = $em->getRepository('xxxx')->findWhateeverYouwant() and and var_dump($var) it show me 0 array seletcted

Comment: Try without sprintf: `$sql = 'query string';`